# Browser Based Video Player Options

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, flash, video

I am looking for a Web Browser Based Video Player (Preferably Flash) which can give me default options (Play,Pause,Slider) & Can give me accurate time in milliseconds where the video is currently played.

I am also interested in more capability in Video Player where User can (Make Clips of the Video and Download the clip), I know flash based based players will support this.

I have tried **[FlowPlayer](http://flowplayer.org/docs/api.html)** , though it is great in basic features, I get current position time in seconds and I am not able to co-relate to my sub titles which is metered in milliseconds.

Multiplying by 1000 doesn't work.

Server Side Code is ASP.NET based.

Comment: The video is not not counted in milliseconds, but in frames per second. So in any position you are on some specific frame. Pal is 25 frames per seconds, so you have 25 places inside a seconds that you can start you subtitles - if you find the frame, you can convert it in milliseconds to type it on your subs

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at he JW player -> http://www.jwplayer.com/
Probably the best player solution with Html5/Flash Support